# Specify that a Subprogram in another package is not blocking?

Tags: ada, spark-ada

SPARK restricts the calling of potentially blocking subprograms from within protected objects.

However, I've noticed if I call ANY subprogram outside of the package in which the protected object lives I get the warning about a potentially blocking subprogram.

What is missing from the external package I'd like to use to tell it the call will be non-blocking? I've tried just putting a "add one to argument" subprogram in another package and it doesn't work. If I move it into the package containing the protected object it does.

What am I missing?

Comment: @DeeDee  -- Posting a MwE, below...

Answer (score 2):

In Ada 2020 there is an attribute `Non_Blocking` which explicitly marks the blocking/nonblocking attributes for static-analysis and the compiler ensuring things are correct.

But this doesn't help if you're stuck in Ada 2012 — and there are specific things that are "potentially blocking" like entry-calls and [IIRC] things like `Ada.Text_IO.Put` — and SPARK takes the reasoning that if it's potentially blocking then you cannot ensure that it's not non-blocking.

According to [the RM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-1.html#I4036), here's what you have to look out for:

> During a protected action, it is a bounded error to invoke an
>   operation that is potentially blocking. The following are defined to
>   be potentially blocking operations:
>
> - a select_statement;
> - an accept_statement;
> - an entry_call_statement;
> - a delay_statement;
> - an abort_statement;
> - task creation or activation;
> - an external call on a protected subprogram (or an external requeue) with the same target object as that of the protected action;
> - a call on a subprogram whose body contains a potentially blocking operation.

So, if the subprogram you're trying to call has a `select`, `accept`, `delay`, or `task` it's potentially blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @shark8 for your detailed answer.

I examined the body of the method I was trying to call and as it was a simple return statement, it did not have any of the effects mentioned in the manual.

I *did* however discover that turning on `SPARK_Mode => On` in the package I am trying to use fixed the issue.

Here's a MwE that reproduces the issue:

```
-- main.adb

pragma Profile (GNAT_Extended_Ravenscar);
pragma Partition_Elaboration_Policy (Sequential);

with P1;

procedure Main is

begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;

-- simple.ads
package Simple is

   procedure Do_Nothing;

end Simple;

-- simple.adb 
package body Simple is

   procedure Do_Nothing is
   begin
      null;
   end Do_Nothing;


end Simple;

-- p1.ads
pragma Profile (GNAT_Extended_Ravenscar);
pragma Partition_Elaboration_Policy (Sequential);

package P1 with 
  SPARK_Mode => On 
is

   protected Protected_Object with 
     SPARK_Mode => On
   is
      procedure Do_Something;
   end Protected_Object;


end P1;

-- p1.adb 
with Simple;

package body P1 with 
  SPARK_Mode => On 
is

   protected body Protected_Object 
   with 
     SPARK_Mode => On 
   is      
      procedure Do_Something is 
      begin
         Simple.Do_Nothing;
      end Do_Something;
   end Protected_Object;


end P1;
```

Comment: I suppose the thing is that, unless you let SPARK see inside the called subprogram, it can’t tell whether it’s blocking or not